# How to get the timezone name from numeric timezone value in Android

Tags: timezone, utc, android-calendar, vcalendar

I am basically trying to read a .vcs file in Android. It has timezone value in the below format:

TZ:+05:30

Now I want to get the timezone name corresponding to this value. Means in this case it would be Kolkata(India).

Is there any code to achieve this in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm assuming you can parse the text into an offset easily enough.)

In general, you can't. Something like "+05:30" just represents an offset from UTC *at one particular time*. It doesn't express how the offset changes within the time zone across the year (or across history). For example, for some of the time the Europe/London time zone has the same offset as Africa/Casablanca - but not always.

Assuming this is associated with a specific date/time, you could use `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs`, iterate over all the time zones, check what the offset from UTC is at that particular instant (using [`TimeZone.getOffset(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset%28long%29)) and see which time zones have the right offset at the right time. There could be many such zones though.

If you *don't* have a specific date/time, it's even more ambiguous. You can use `getRawOffset` and `getDSTSavings` to see whether the target offset is *either* the standard *or* DST offset for any particular zone - although note that these calls assume that for a particular time zone, the DST offset and standard offset remain the same across history (which isn't always true).

Comment: Yes this is specific to a particular date/time and we are assuming that the offset will not change. Means we can assume is to be same within the timezone across the year.

Comment: @user1423581: Wow - that cuts out a *lot* of time zones. In that case, you can use `getRawOffset` and `observesDaylightTime` to filter.

Answer (score 1):

```
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-06:00");

        String tzarr[] = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(tz.getRawOffset());
        for(int i=0;i<tzarr.length;i++)
```

Comment: It will give all the values that correspond to GMT-6..Means around 6 values in total.